# VSS / TFS Checkin related

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

As an source safe user with admin privilege, how do i perform following actions in TFS/VSS.

(a) Find a/all user(s) who checked in code for a specific day

(b) Find all check-in by a specific user based on some date range

(b) Find user who did the last checkin along with list files that he modified/added. This should be at
    TFS/VSS project level.

Comment: Do you want instructions for VSS or TFS? Both are source control repositories and function differently when it comes to viewing history and finding check-ins etc.

Comment: @Alicia, Advise me with what you know irrespective of whether it is TFS or VSS and I will workout the rest.

Comment: Have you done any investigation of your own? You can get a lot of data from the UI in VS. Alternatively, you can also use the TF history command line http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VSS, you can do the filter in History options dialog box.

[image]

For TFS, you can use 'Find changeset' command.

[image]

Comment: This is not what I asked. After reading through the link, I can't find any point which talked about what I wanted. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @Nair I've updated my answer. please check again and see if this is what you want.